# Getting RSS using JQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'm new to RSS parsing and am having trouble using jQuery to access feeds. I tried (and would like to) use `$.get()` but that got me less than this. (This at least triggers the error.) What am I doing wrong?

```
function GetFedFeeds(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.federalreserve.gov/feed/press_enforcement.xml',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml){
            $(xml).find('item').each( function(){
                var t = $(this).find('title').text();
                $('#content').append(t);
            });
        },
        error: function() { alert('RSS Error'); }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use server-side languages like PHP to get data from an external URL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying for Cross-domain, which will won't work.

JSONP is the approach for cross-domain request.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,
`url` is the RSS feed source URL

```
$.ajax({
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/service/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //YOUR DATA
        }
    });
```